# How can i get online json data more fast and store in javascript variable?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to get json record from online json file and store it into javascript variable. In json file there are near about **46000** records of airports. I am trying to get it on while page is loading.

The json file is [this](http://data.okfn.org/data/core/airport-codes/r/airport-codes.csv.json)

Below is my javascript code:

```
var source = $.getValues("http://data.okfn.org/data/core/airport-codes/r/airport-codes.csv.json");
```

Here, I am storing json file record in "source" variable. I am storing this json record for autocomplete functionality for textbox. But page takes more time to load. Is there any way to get fast result for the same.

Comment: Store it once, doesn't look like there's much changing in the list (as long as the airports don't fly themselve). [Redis](http://redis.io) is  good for stuff like that.

Comment: Please be more precise when describing your problem. One thing is server side optimisation, another one client side optimisation - Is the problem waiting for the json data to be loaded, or with the browser filtering/rendering the 46k items slowly?

Comment: Sounds like you want an offline process that reads this data and stores it somewhere locally. Your online app should then read the data from this local datastore, not the online system. this is provided your data doesn't change very often

Comment: It does not look like a good idea to me to actually access the JSON file of 13MB directly or to keep it in the browser cache. Both alternatives seem very clunky to me. What about setting up a backend server page using some database functionality to cache the contents and then serve you with a filtered selection for the autocomplete process?

Comment: will it work fast onkeyup searching without storing it in variable while loading page?

Comment: A database is much better suited for the task of looking up data in a large table than the browser using only JavaScript and arrays. The jquery  autocomplete package (like others) provides a fast and easy interface to ajax datasources, see here [jquery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote).